# libgdx (Ashley Framework ECS) - What is the proper way of talking system to another system?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

**`System` to `System`**

Currently I'm developing `CharacterSystem`, `GunSystem`, `BulletSystem` using ashley framework. My problem is I dont know if this is the proper way of talking `system` to other `system`.

My `CharacterSystem` method `onProcessEntity` when the `character` `attack` is triggered I used `getEngine().getSystem(GunSystem.class).trigger(true)` and inside the `GunSystem` I have a method the Generate entity of a `Bullet`. While the `BulletSystem` handles the freeing of bodies, when outside the camera.

**sub-question** What is the proper way of creating `Bullet` `class` with ECS framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used Ashley as ECS but usually `Systems` should not communicate with each other.

**Reason**: When `Systems` would communicate they would not be independent of each other. Independent `Systems` allow you to freely add and remove them without having to worry the code breaks. The game logic probably breaks of course when a important `Systems` are missing.

Have a `Factory` (class) which does create the bullet entity. Then use the `Factory` in each `System` which can built new bullet entity.

Comment: I am using libgdx, what do you recommend ECS framework to use with libgdx?

Comment: Ashley or artemis-odb. Do not know any other ECS.

Answer (score 5):

I use the Ashley ECS quite a lot for games and in a recent project (https://github.com/basimkhajwal/LSD) I ran into a similar situation. My method probably isn't standard and it may have issues which would occur in a different project setup but using an *event queue* has been a good solution for me.

In essence, you have an `enum` (in my case `GameEvent`) which handles all the different events needing to be passed around like `PLAYER_DIED`, `LAUNCH_PLAYER` and so on. I used Ashley's `signals` interface to create a simple queued store of events that a system can poll on each tick. As follows:

```
public class EventQueue implements Listener<GameEvent> {

    private PriorityQueue<GameEvent> eventQueue;

    public EventQueue() {
        eventQueue = new PriorityQueue<GameEvent>();
    }

    public GameEvent[] getEvents() {
        GameEvent[] events = eventQueue.toArray(new GameEvent[0]);
        eventQueue.clear();
        return events;
    }

    public GameEvent poll() {
        return eventQueue.poll();
    }

    @Override
    public void receive(Signal<GameEvent> signal, GameEvent event) { 
        eventQueue.add(event);
    }

}
```

Next, in my `GameWorld` class, the one which loads the Ashley `Engine` and populates it with systems, I have a single `Signal<GameEvent>` which is the main backbone for my event queue. Here, like `Listener<T>`, `Signal<T>` is already part of Ashley.

Some systems then need to be able to fire into this signal / receive events from it so they take this `Signal` class in the constructor. The `EntitySystem` can then bind a listener or fire events which would then be passed on to other listeners. E.g. my `LaserSystem` class (simplified):

```
public class LaserSystem extends IteratingSystem implements Disposable, ContactListener {

    ...    

    private Signal<GameEvent> gameEventSignal;
    private EventQueue eventQueue;

    public LaserSystem(Signal<GameEvent> gameEventSignal) {
        super(Family.all(LaserComponent.class).get(), Constants.SYSTEM_PRIORITIES.LASER);

        this.gameEventSignal = gameEventSignal;

        eventQueue = new EventQueue();
        gameEventSignal.add(eventQueue);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

        ....

        LaserComponent laserComponent = laserMapper.get(laser);
        laserComponent.updateLaser = true;

        if (other.getComponent(PlayerComponent.class) != null) {
            gameEventSignal.dispatch(GameEvent.LASER_COLLISION);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense, also feel free to read my project code for more example usage.

Comment: And to go a step further, couldn't you even store event instances of special classes, so you can pass parameters to events?